# How to do this in Blender 2.79b?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Sorry, I really don't know what to call the title! And I just don't know what they are called

But I really need to know how to do this? I need to make those rib looking thingys on the sides and roof of my model I'm working on

I tried everywhere and can't find any information exactly on how to model those thingys on the side and roof! See attached photo "Sorry, it's poor quality I downloaded the photo off Google for my reference for my project but I've cropped the original image too"

If someone could tell me how exactly to do this in Blender 2.79 as well as making it flow from the roof to the sides as I array it would be great

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: How realistic does it need to be? If this is mostly going to be a distant shot, you can probably get away with using bump mapping and a procedural wave texture.

Comment: I am looking to model it as realistic as possible as I am doing a full detailed high-poly model, I would also prefer not to use any bump mapping texture